how to use ktor or networking in kmp web wasm project
I have downloaded the kmp project from kotlin wizard online everything works fine for mobile applications but when it comes to wasm web it does resolve dependencies here is the error :composeApp:wasmJsTest: Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.7.
Required by:
project :composeApp
Possible solution:

Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
can anyone help me out please?

when I remove the dependencies from main it works fine, maybe I'm missing something

heeey, I got something similar! Whenever I try to add literally ANY 3-party lib to the KMP project, I see that exact error. And yes, only for that wasmJs module.
And so I can't reach the objects from the lib within wasmJs module, while I CAN within Android module.
Do you have any ideas?
Or maybe that's because we use that Kotlin Wizard Online, and it states that the Web part is only alpha(

Hi, yes wasmJs is in alpha that's why it causes error to any third party, hopefully we get this fixed when we will have stable wasmJs

Ktor is only adding wasm support in 3.0.0, which is in beta now - you can try it out already, 3.0.0-beta-2 is the latest atm
